# How to use SOAP in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, soap, meteor

I'm the beginner in MeteorJS. Now I have a problem, I need to parse it http://www.nbrb.by/Services/ExRates.asmx?WSDL
For meteor.js I found this package https://atmospherejs.com/zardak/soap
But I don't know how to work with it, because when I try to use it: "Soap is not defined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the code that uses Soap
eg.

```
var client = Soap.createClient(url);
```

is on the server. Since from the Atmosphere page: "node-soap isn't packaged for browser usage and thus, meteor-soap is avalible only server-side."

Moving it to my server folder fixed that problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this package is broken... i don't see an [api.export](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export) of the Soap object for you to use in [package.js](https://github.com/zardak/meteor-soap/blob/master/package.js). Maybe you could submit a fix to the git repo and get the package updated.